# How to understand the index of np.array

Tags: arrays, numpy-ndarray

I am learning python numpy.array and am confused about how the index works. Let's see I have the following 3x4 2D array:

```
A = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [ 5, 6, 7, 8],
              [ 9,10,11,12]])
```

If I want to extract the 1 from this array, I need to input the index of that number, which is A[0,0]

Out of curiosity I also tried the following

```
B = A[[0,0]]

C = A[[0],[0]]
```

B turns out to be a 2x4 2D array:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

C turns out to be a 1D array of 1 element:

```
array([1])
```

I am wondering how indexing of B and C works and why I obtain those arrays?

Answer (score 0):

In B, you are only giving one index for a 2 dimensional array which is `[0,0]`. So it will return the element in the first dimension of the index  given (0 and 0 here).

So, for the first index (which is 0) it will return the first element in the first dimension which is `[1,2,3,4]` and it will go for the next index given which is again 0, so it will print two `[1,2,3,4]` as you have got.

Next in the C, you have given 2 indices for a 2 dimensional array which are `[0]` and `[0]`. So it will go through the first dimension for the index 0 which is `[1,2,3,4]` and in that element it will return the 0th position which is `[1]` as you have got.

For better understanding, let's see another case `A[[0,1],2]`.

Here, we have given 2 indices for a 2 dimensional array which are `[0,1]` and `2`. So, we get the elements which are in the index `[0,2]` and next with `[1,2]`.Th output will be `[3,7]`.

The thing is it will iterate through all possible combinations of indices given and return those values in those indices.